# How can I use AngularJs within a working Durandal application?

Tags: angularjs, durandal

How can I use AngularJs within a working durandal application? 
If you could give a tutorial or a lesson. That would be much appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? They are competing frameworks that do the same things differently. Choose one or the other.

Comment: @Brett i'm maintaining a legacy application that is currently using durandal and we are trying to introduce angular into the new modules we create. Having that said, it's currently not feasible to rewrite the entire application with angular, however I know we can introduce angular with the new client code we write.

Comment: I understand, but there's a reason you cannot find a demo or tutorial of what you're looking for - it's not a good idea and doesn't make much sense. Durandal isn't broken or unsupported, so I'm not sure why you'd force Angular on it. You're asking for more problems than it's worth, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Is Angular a must? Knockout fills much of the same role as Angular; however Durandal is built on top of Knockout, so they play very nicely together.